# Material Ripple Effect: Dark Theme vs. Light Theme

Tags: android, material-design

My view consists of a `RecyclerView` with `CardView` rows. The ripple effect when clicking on it, is only working when I use the `Theme.Material.Light` as `AppTheme`.

As soon as I switch to the dark version (`Theme.Material`) its not working anymore.

Any ideas whats the problem here? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "not working anymore?" be more spécifique, maybe post your Theme content

Comment: the ripple effect is not working. simply no click feedback when using the dark theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me. The ripple effect for the dark themes is white, of course. Therefore I was not seeing it on the white CardView.

Comment:  So funny.....